# PCRE regex and spaces

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm working on this regex:

```
/\{(\w+)::(\w+)::([\sa-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/
```

So, from a long string, I could get patterns like: Word::Word::Word and word and word

I've tested this regex here: http://regex101.com/

And in PHP it sais it should work fine.

But when I put into code, it doesn't work:

```
$pattern = '/\{(\w+)::(\w+)::([\sa-zA-Z]+)\}/';

echo preg_match_all(preg_match_all($pattern,'{WORD::WORD::PRUEB ASDF ASD}', $expr,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER));
```

the echo result is 0

Comment: why are you calling this preg_match_all function twice. 
echo preg_match_all($pattern,'{WORD::WORD::PRUEB ASDF ASD}', $expr,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

Comment: echo `preg_match_all(preg_match_all` ? You're echoing the number of matches of a number of matches?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling preg_match_all inside preg_match_all. Do this instead:

```
$pattern = '/\{(\w+)::(\w+)::([\sa-zA-Z]+)\}/';
echo preg_match_all($pattern,'{WORD::WORD::PRUEB ASDF ASD}', $expr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Anyway, on monday i'll copy full code, because i had it without the two calls and it doesn't work properly